# how to get data using using flask mongoengine

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine,flask and i am try to insert the data into db 
my code

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from mongoengine import  connect
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGODB_DB'] = 'programming'
db = MongoEngine(app)
connect('db')
@app.route('/add', methods = ['POST'])
def add_data():
    #language = {'name':'pyhton'}
    db.languages.insert( {'name': request.form.get('name','python')})
    return jsonify({'message':"Inserted Succesfuuly"})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=8000)
```

> Error: 
>        File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/flaskapi/helloapi.py", line 21, in add_data
>           db.languages.insert( {'name': request.form.get('name','Ravi')})
>       AttributeError: 'MongoEngine' object has no attribute 'languages'

Help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you cannot use collections on your db like this. The `db = MongoEngine(app)` configure your database setting. So you need define `languages` collections like this:

```
class languages(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()
    ...

@app.route('/add', methods = ['POST'])
def add_data():
    #language = {'name':'python'}
    lang = languages(name=request.form.get('name','python'))
    lang.save()
    return jsonify({'message':"Inserted Succesfuuly"})
```

if you want to insert into already created `languages` collection, you can use `pymongo`:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.db_name
@app.route('/add', methods = ['POST'])
def add_data():
    #language = {'name':'pyhton'}
    db.languages.insert_one( {'name': request.form.get('name','python')})
    return jsonify({'message':"Inserted Succesfuuly"})
```